# How to change the parent menu item without breaking the children in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, menu, tree, move

I want to change the parent of a menu tree on a node update. I'm using the module named "rules" to access the update event and I have this code as follows:

```
if ($node->taxonomy[1] == "1") {
    $plid = 440;
} else if ($node->taxonomy[1] == "2") {
    $plid = 379;
}
if($plid) {
    db_query("UPDATE {menu_links} SET plid='".$plid."', p1='".$plid."' WHERE link_path='"."node/".$node->nid."'");
}
```

The problem is that this $node which is updated also has some child menu items under it, in the primary menu and when I update the node to change the parent, its children just end up one level higher and don't get moved with current menu item. Is there an easy way to move a whole menu tree from one parent menu item to another?

I want this,

-**parent1**

--*child1*

---sub-child1

---sub-child2

-**parent2**

to be this:

-**parent1**

-**parent2**

--*child1*

---sub-child1

---sub-child2

<strike>Can you help me?</strike> Is there a Drupal-way of doing this? =)

I know that this code makes a lot of assumptions but I need it just for one specific case

Comment: It is a very bad idea to "manually" update the database table and a lot of hoorible things can (and will) happen in and around the menu, the routers, the cache, the aliases and a lot more. Do you /insist/ on running this database update code?

Comment: No, it was just a bad attempt. I've put it there just to clarify what I'm really trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by experimenting with the API:

```
<?php
    $result = db_query("SELECT mlid FROM {menu_links} WHERE link_path='%s'", "node/".$node->nid);
    $oldItem = db_fetch_array($result);
    $oldLinkItem = menu_link_load($oldItem[mlid]);
    $oldLinkItem[plid] = $plid;
    menu_link_save($oldLinkItem);
?>
```

Just needed to figure out that I didn't have to deal with those "p0" to "p8" when saving the new menu item. Drupal seems to automatically move the children. By the way, I could use a more reliable way of getting mlid of nodes menu item.

Answer (score -1):

Use the Drupal API to perform these operations; you will find it much easier. If you wanted to do it using database queries (which I must absolutely advise you do not), you would write a recursive algorithm that performed the move of the tree.

Comment: This is much better served as a comment. As an answer, it's most unhelpful.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I really appreciate it but I already looked through the API and couldn't really figure out how to do it. Could you please be more specific?